# How can I add values to this array using onClick

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to add new comments everytime I click my onClick button. However when I add new comments I don't want the old comments to go away, so I decided that what I am going to do is add the values to array and just map through it. However the way I am adding values to my array its giving me multiple arrays everytime I click the button. I want to click the button and I want the new value to appear in next to the old value in the array. Please help me solve this problem.

```
 handleChangeComment(event) {
  const myValue = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    commentArea: [myValue]
  })
}

handleClickComment = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
   this.setState(({ clicked }) => ({ clicked: clicked + 1 }));
   this.setState(({ commentClick }) => ({ commentClick: commentClick + 1 }))
   let comment = this.state.commentArea
   let newComment = comment
   let currentComment = this.state.commentInfo;      
   let newComments = currentComment;
   newComments.push(newComment);
   console.log(newComments)
   let commentClick = this.state.commentClick


  let postInfoCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.postInfo))
  postInfoCopy[commentClick].comment = [newComments]
  this.setState({
      postInfo: postInfoCopy
    }) 



}
```

Comment: Can we see the render() method?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve by adding spread operator `...` to the array to get it's value and concat it to an single array

```
handleClickComment = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
       this.setState(({ clicked }) => ({ clicked: clicked + 1 }));
       this.setState(({ commentClick }) => ({ commentClick: commentClick + 1 }))
       let comment = this.state.commentArea
       let newComment = comment
       let currentComment = this.state.commentInfo;      
       let newComments = [...currentComment, ...newComment]
       let commentClick = this.state.commentClick
```

`let newComments = [...currentComment, ...newComment]`